# htmlunit not able to load jquery script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit

I am starting selenium standalone webserver using command

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -trustAllSSLCertificates`

The python code starting client is

`from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities={'browserName':'htmlunit', 'platform':'ANY', 'setThrowExceptionOnScriptError':False, 'javascriptEnabled':True, 'acceptSslCerts':True})
driver.get('https://testvip08.mserv.local')`

and getting following error

> 11:36:10.832 ERROR - runtimeError: message=[The data necessary to
>   complete this operation is not yet  available.]
>   sourceName=[https://testvip08.mserv.local/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js]
>   line=[19] lineSo urce=[null] lineOffset=[0] 11:36:10.848 ERROR -
>   runtimeError: message=[The data necessary to complete this operation
>   is not yet  available.]
>   sourceName=[https://testvip08.mserv.local/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js]
>   line=[19] lineSo urce=[null] lineOffset=[0] 11:36:10.864 ERROR -
>   runtimeError: message=[The data necessary to complete this operation
>   is not yet  available.]
>   sourceName=[https://testvip08.mserv.local/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js]
>   line=[19] lineSo urce=[null] lineOffset=[0] 11:36:11.442 WARN -
>   Automation server can't create object for 'EUTrace.EUTracer'.
>   11:36:11.442 ERROR - runtimeError: message=[Automation server can't
>   create object for 'EUTrace.EUTra cer'.]
>   sourceName=[https://testvip08.mserv.local/scripts/SWLogger.js]
>   line=[75] lineSource=[null] li neOffset=[0]

Making `javascriptEnabled:False` doesn't work either. Also have tried turning logging off for

`logging.getLogger('com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit').setLevel(0)
logging.getLogger('org.apache.http').setLevel(0)`

None of above is working.

Answer (score 0):

More details are needed.

The error you see can be safely ignored, also HtmlUnit 2.16 was recently released, and it would be better to direct test it.

Comment: What more details are required? Any specifics?

Comment: It is better if the URL is provided, so others can compare HtmlUnit behavior with real browsers.